# How to fix handlebars that have virtually turned into a seesaw

Tags: handlebars

I have a Roadmaster Granite Peak Women's Bike. It was really cheap, but I'm not sure if this issue has to do with the quality of the bike or how it was put together. The issue is the handlebar has loosened and is like a seesaw because it slid out of the piece that holds it in place, the part in the red circle. However, they are not loose enough to just slide right back into place. How would I fix this? Thanks in advance[image: ![exactly the bike I have]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeayc.jpg)

Comment: Did this happened after tightening the bolt all the way?

Comment: Was it always like this?  Need to figure out if the bar is just too small for the stem, or if the stem has stretched, or the bolt(s) holding the stem around the bar has stretched.    Could be that it was never assembled properly and simply needs some loctite, or it could be an endemic problem with a low-end BSO.

Comment: There's no point fixing the symptom and ignoring the root cause.   Losing your handlebars while riding is a guaranteed crash.

Comment: Get the appropriate wrench (probably a metric "allen" wrench -- available from any bike shop or hardware store if you take the bike in to match).  Loosen the clamp bolt (directly under the clamp around the bar).  Slide the bar into place and tighten the clamp bolt.  Or let a bike shop do it.  In rare cases you may need a "shim" from a piece of pop can.

Answer (score 1):

Cut a piece from an aluminum can and insert it.  Aluminum is soft and it will (hopefully) clamp in.